# Cannot Alter Column in Squirell SQL Client

Tags: sql, database, database-schema, ingres

I am trying to alter a column in my ingres DB to expand the size of the column.

The query i'm running is

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN address varchar(100) NOT NULL
```

Which gives error

> Error: ALTER TABLE: invalid change of attributes on an ALTER COLUMN
>
> SQLState:  42000 ErrorCode: 3859

Anyone any idea why I'm getting this error? I've checked the syntax for altering tables.

Comment: Try: `ALTER TABLE test_table MODIFY address varchar(100) NOT NULL`

Comment: No luck. "Error: line 2, Syntax error on 'MODIFY'.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a varchar(<100) right now? is it nullable? If it isn't nullable you will probably have to mention default value for the empty rows.

Comment: Yeah it's varchar 50 now, the "is_nullable" column is set to YES

Comment: So just deleted the NOT NULL and it worked

Comment: Simply the point is you have null in data. `UPDATE test_table SET address='' WHERE address IS NULL`; and then try changing to `NOT NULL`

Comment: I just deleted the NOT NULL from my originally query and it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `NULL` in data. Update your table first (set to empty string or any value you want):

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375507)**

```
UPDATE test_table
SET address = ''         -- or another value indicating missing addres like 'none'
WHERE address IS NULL;
```

And then try:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN address varchar(100) NOT NULL;
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to enforce `NOT NULL` use just:

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375514)**

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN address varchar(100);
```

Comment: I just deleted the NOT NULL from my original query and it worked?

Comment: @gio10245 The point is you have NULL in data. When you ALTER TABLE and set NOT NULL it can't be enforced because of NULL. Update table then alter it and it should work

Comment: But it's working now by simply just removing the NOT NULL from my original query so why do I need to do this?

Comment: @gio10245 Question is do you want address that contain `NULL` or not? See demo I provided.

Comment: All i want to do is expand size, I wasn't sure if I needed "NOT NULL". The value in this column can be NULL if it wants to be so I removed the NOT NULL and it works?

Comment: @gio10245 Then yes use just `ALTER TABLE test_table ALTER COLUMN address varchar(100);` and allow to be NULL.